# Shared element return transition blinks

Tags: android, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I am writing a custom return transition for when an activity is returned to the calling activity. The transition fades the finishing activity's content into the final position of the calling activity. However, when that animation completes, the calling activity's shared element simply blinks into the final position.

Here's a snippet from my transition's `createAnimator`:

```
@Override
public Animator createAnimator(ViewGroup sceneRoot, TransitionValues startValues,
        TransitionValues endValues) {
    if (startValues == null || endValues == null) {
        return null;
    }

    final ViewGroup startView = (ViewGroup) startValues.view;
    final int startHeight = (int) startValues.values.get(PROPERTY_HEIGHT);
    final int startWidth = (int) startValues.values.get(PROPERTY_WIDTH);

    // Position at the original location
    final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(startWidth,
            View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(startHeight,
            View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    startView.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
    startView.layout(0, 0, startWidth, startHeight);

    final ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(startView, "dummyValue", 0f, 1f);
    animator.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
        // Shift start view into end view's frame and fade out at the same time
    });
    return animator;
}
```

I can't seem to find a way to tell the view in the re-enter transition to fade in at the same time. In the above animator, the `startValues.view` and `endValues.view` seems to correspond to the same object (which is why I had to reposition the start view to its original location).

Answer (score 0):

why you dont use the callbacks ? **setExitSharedElementCallback** and **setEnterSharedElementCallback** do your view animation inside setEnterShare... callback of second activity...  hope this helps you.

```
setExitSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSharedElementEnd(List<String> sharedElementNames, List<View> sharedElements, List<View> sharedElementSnapshots) {                        
                    super.onSharedElementEnd(sharedElementNames, sharedElements, sharedElementSnapshots);
                }
            });
```